# Merging two bones that are children of 'one' parent

Tags: pose-mode

enter image description hereThere are two child bones - sleeve bone, hand bone.
And there is a parent bone - arm bone

And the sleeve bone and hand bone both are one down below from arm bone. which means they are direct child of arm bone.

I don't know how to merge these two bones into one, while automatically keeping the two bones' parent relationship to mesh into one bone that just has been made.

In internet search, they say press Alt+M or just merge, but it won't work as what it says, I'm guessing because these two bones I'm trying to merge together aren't a parent-child relationship. I should not delete any bone, since it will mess up the armarture's parenting mesh, and to re-parent mesh to changed armarture, it will take so many time.[image]

Comment: Hi Shinhu, I see you have tagged your question with *inverse-kinematics*, how is inverse kinematics related to your question?

Comment: In Blender there is no way to merge bones. You can only delete either bone or change the parent relationship.

Comment: Hello. Sorry, the reason why I added 'ik' is... because the final aim for this is to make a arm able to do inverse-kinematic. but since this bone has some parallel children like sleeve and hand, when I try to 'copy rotation' together with 'Inverse kinematic' constraint to a same bone, matching two constraints to the same target bone, it goes weirdly freaking out. I don't know why. I'll add more screenshots and a link that I watched for tutorial learning.

Comment: if you want to delete, let say, bone1, and you want to keep, let say, bone2, with influence of bone1 being given to bone2, you can delete bone1, then go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, select bone1 group, press Select, select bone2 group, press Assign, now the vertex group that was linked to bone1 is linked to bone2... is it what you want?

Comment: YES! Wow, I really never thought I could visually see and keep the bones' vertexes like that. I should go watch more videos about vertex group. Question solved. Thank you so much. I also removed the ik tag. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete, let say, bone1, and you want to keep, let say, bone2, with influence of bone1 being given to bone2, you can delete bone1, then go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Group*s, select bone1 group, press *Select*, select bone2 group, press *Assign*, now the vertex group that was linked to bone1 is linked to bone2.